# Cannot generate date array with adding missing dates and fill with previously known value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Pls.help me to finish query.

I have a table:

```
select 
     date(datetime_from) as datetime_from, 
     listing_id, 
     price_cents_usd
    from `data_marts.pg_listings_log`
```

with the result:

| id | date | listing_id | va1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-07 | 769345 | 172905577 |
| 2 | 2020-11-27 | 769345 | 172905577 |
| 3 | 2020-09-29 | 769345 | 169713711 |

The main goal is to create date array from '2020-01-01' to current date and to fill gaps with values from previous known value.

The query I am using is:

```
with log as (
    select 
     date(datetime_from) as datetime_from, 
     listing_id, 
     price_cents_usd
    from `data_marts.pg_listings_log`
),
day as(
    select dates
    from UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', current_date(), interval 1 day)) dates
)
select distinct
 dates,
 listing_id,
 ifnull(first_value(price_cents_usd ignore nulls) over(partition by listing_id order by dates ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND
 UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),1) as va1
from day 
cross join log
where listing_id=769345
order by dates desc
```

This query pulls the result with newly generated dates array, but includes all possibly known values to every single date:

[image]

What I need is to have all dates within date range ('2020-01-01' to current_date) and to fill them with previous known value:

| id | date | listing_id | va1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-22 | 769345 | 172905577 |
| 2 | 2021-07-21 | 769345 | 172905577 |
| 3 | 2021-07-20 | 769345 | 172905577 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mena by "What I need is to have all dates within date range and to fill them with previous known value."? Could you share an example of the output you are expecting? Plus, do you expect to have more than one record per day?

Comment: @AleixCC I have edited question, it should be clear now :)

Comment: What value do you want to show in the output? The maximum value from the previous day?

Comment: @AleixCC yes, exactly

Comment: What are the values before 2020-09-29?  Your question isn't 100% clear to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff there are absolutely random dates that's why I didn't provide all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  day as datetime_from, 
  a.listing_id, 
  last_value(price_cents_usd ignore nulls) over(partition by a.listing_id order by day rows between unbounded preceding and current row) price_cents_usd
from (select distinct listing_id from `data_marts.pg_listings_log`) a,
unnest(generate_date_array('2020-01-01', current_date)) day
left join `data_marts.pg_listings_log` b  
on date(datetime_from) = day
and a.listing_id = b.listing_id 
# order by datetime_from
```

Comment: this is absolutely amazing! thank you so much!

Comment: this is absolutely amazing! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As per what I understood, you will need to tweak your original query for the following:

```
with log as (
    select 
     date(datetime_from) as datetime_from, 
     listing_id, 
     max(price_cents_usd) as max_price_cents_usd
    from `data_marts.pg_listings_log`
    group by 1, 2
),
day as(
    select dates
    from UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', current_date(), interval 1 day)) dates
)
select distinct
 dates,
 listing_id,
 lag(max_price_cents_usd) over(partition by listing_id order by dates) as va1
from day 
cross join log
where listing_id=769345
```

Check it out and let me know if it works!

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. Your code pulls the same result as my does

Comment: do you have a bigger data sample? my code works but I guess that only 3 rows of data are not representative enough :/

Comment: @AlexCC yes there are more than 3 rows. It was just an axample of how data is organized